# How to convert string to byteArray, when the string comes from a BLOB?

Tags: java, android

I converted a BLOB from SQite to String , and i want to convert that string to byteArray to but don't work. please help me.

convert BLOb to string on ArrayList HashMap:

```
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
            user.put("username" , cursor.getString(9));
            user.put("photo" , cursor.getBlob(10).toString());
            ImageList.add(user);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
```

With the following code , I'm unable to convert string i got above to ByteArray, when i run i get nothing on ImageView :

```
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> photoList;
    photoList = db.getString();
    HashMap<String, String> hashmap= photoList.get(0);

    String photo_name = hashmap.get("photo");
    byte[] byteArray = photo_name.getBytes();

    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
    imageview.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Comment: Using BLOBS is an anti-pattern. You'd better stor the paths of your images and load them from the storage.

Comment: @BernoulliGate, thank you , but i can't use the path , because this image which is in `sqlite` i brought it from mysql as base64 and i stored it to sqlite, now i want to retrieve it as string then i convert it

Answer (score -1):

```
public class ConvertStringIntoBytes{

public void convertStringToByteArray() {
    String stringToConvert = "This is test string";
    byte[] theByteArray = stringToConvert.getBytes();
    System.out.println(theByteArray.length);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Main().convertStringToByteArray();
    }
}
```

Code to convert the string to byte array.